# Can't run part of method when method is called from another class

Tags: java, netbeans

I implemented method for highlighting words in jTextPane. Everything is working fine if I call that method from main class, but if I call that method from another class while loop do not work. Here is my code:

```
// Main class with my method, I named it Frame

public void traziJedan(String rijec){
        try{
        Highlighter h = jTextPane1.getHighlighter();
        h.removeAllHighlights();
        String text = jTextPane1.getText();
        String pattern = rijec;
        int pos = 0;

        while ((pos = text.indexOf(pattern, pos)) >= 0) {
                System.out.println(rijec);
                h.addHighlight(pos, pos + pattern.length(), DefaultHighlighter.DefaultPainter);
                pos += pattern.length();

            }

        }
        catch(BadLocationException e){}
    }

// method in another class

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        Frame f = new Frame();
        f.traziJedan(jTextField1.getText());
    }
```

System.out.println(rijec);  I put this here only to see if this method is working, but this word is not printed out only in while loop, if I put this command anywhere else I get correct output. What's the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You should update the `jTextPane1` or any UI component from the UI thread, you can use invokeLater or invokeAndWait

e.g.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    // update UI
  }
});
```

Comment: ok, but why doesn't while loop working. I think it should print out the passed word. If I put "System.out.println(rijec);" above while loop, then it prints text that I need.

Comment: Try to call updateUI() to refresh the jTextPane1. But still you *have* to run this from the UI thread

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your `jTextPane1` is not correctly initialized when you allocate a new Frame: `Frame f = new Frame();` in your `jButton1ActionPerformed` method.

Don't allocate a new `Frame` when you use the method from another class, instead pass in the existing Frame instance.

Comment: then how to initialise it correctly. GUI is made using NetBeans GUI editor.

Comment: The problem seems to be that you allocate a completely fresh instance of `Frame`. I cannot say more without seeing more of your code.

Comment: If you create a new Frame instance you will get an empty jTextPane1 (line 42, `jTextPane1 = new javax.swing.JTextPane();`). It is clear, that the pattern cannot be found in this empty text pane.

Comment: so do you have any idea how to solve this. Is there any other way to call that method which I need without creating new Frame instance